# JS Inheritance example: too much recursion

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, recursion, overriding

Sorry for dump question I am new to js. I would like to override `f2()` function in `D` "class". But for some reason Fire Fox told me: "too much recursion". Could you please point me where recursion happening and how to make this code work as expected?

```
var B = function () {
};
B.prototype.f2 = function (x) {
    return 2 * x;
};

var C = function () {
    B.call(this);
};

var D = function () {
    C.call(this);
};

D.prototype.f2 = function (x) {
    return C.prototype.f2.call(this, x) * 7;
};

inherit(B, C);
inherit(C, D);

function inherit(Child, Parent) {
    Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
}

var d = new D();
console.log(d.f2(3));
```

Comment: I'm curious why you're studying ES5 prototype chains so intently (based on this and at least one other question of yours I've answered). The `inherit` function above is outdated. As of ES2015, there's a simple, clear, declarative syntax for this, and that syntax can be transpiled for older environments that don't support it yet. It's **much** easier to understand in that syntax. So studying this outdated way of doing it seems...non-optimal.

Comment: *(not my dv ...)*

Comment: Thank you a lot, your answers are very helpful! I attended training about classical oop pattern in js, and we were asked to implement it in a two ways ES5 and ES2015. But I see what you are saying, it makes sense and makes js world ,that I just get acquainted with, more clear.

Comment: I was just curious. :-) Good luck with your explorations!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You need to set up the `XYZ.prototype` objects **before** you try to add properties to them. Since your `inherit` function creates them, you must ensure that you do things in the right order.
2. You have the order of the parent and child backward in your `inherit` calls. It's `inherit(child, parent)`, not `inherit(parent, child)`.

```js
var B = function () {
};
B.prototype.f2 = function (x) {
    return 2 * x;
};

var C = function () {
    B.call(this);
};
inherit(C, B);            // *** Moved and updated

var D = function () {
    C.call(this);
};
inherit(D, C);            // *** Moved and updated

D.prototype.f2 = function (x) {
    return C.prototype.f2.call(this, x) * 7;
};

function inherit(Child, Parent) {
    Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
}

var d = new D();
console.log(d.f2(3));
```

The ES2015 version, for comparison:

```js
class B {
  f2(x) {
    return 2 * x;
  }
}

class C extends B {
}

class D extends C {
  f2(x) {
    return super.f2(x) * 7;
  }
}

const d = new D();
console.log(d.f2(3));
```